# SharePoint localize menu items

Tags: sharepoint

SharePoint can be used in many different languages which is great. Some SharePoint sites however only support one language because it is only one used by the users. When this language isn't English you can get into some troubles when you are not familiar with SharePoint and try to google stuff. What I would like to find is the localization files that translates the menu items in the settings pages to help me map my google results to what I see on my screen (which isn't in English). Is the translations available somewhere, like an xml file or is the translations located in the database or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the location for the localization files in

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\Resources
```

I'm guessing that this path can be different depending on which version of SharePoint you have.

The files that had the translations I was looking for was in the files that have core in the filename. For example, the site setting links translations can be found if you search for  in the core.en-us.resx file.